# Generate XML Schema with documentation

Tags: xsd, jaxb, xml-binding

Is there a way to generate XML Schema(xsd) with documentation(`<xsd:annotation> / <xsd:documentation>`) from javadoc comments in classes?
I know the reverse is possible (i.e generation classes with javadoc comments from xsd with comments).

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [JAXBContext.generateSchema(SchemaOutputResolver)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html#generateSchema%28javax.xml.bind.SchemaOutputResolver%29) API it is not possible for Javadoc comments to be included in <xsd:documentation> sections. The reason for this is that there isn't any API available to introspect the Java class/field/property to get the information in the comments.

Comment: so jaxb doesn't support the above feature?

Comment: Right, as the Java language does not support the means to provide such a feature.

Answer (score 1):

When javadoc doesn't work: How about an annotation (something like @XmlDocumentation(lang="en" content="..."))?

Comment: If such annotation is possible, then it sounds like a good idea to me

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible right now with the **jaxb2-maven-plugin**

http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/index.html

But the recommendation is to use the XmlType annotation, for me the javadocs were working only when i dont use the attribute name of this annotation. I think is a bug with the default javadoc renderer.