# Generate XSD from Java WITH documentation

Tags: xsd, jaxb

1. I created an XSD schema and have put in some documentation via the  tag.
2. from the XSD i generated Java classes using Jaxb (from within eclipse - jdk1.6)
3. i now plan to use my java classes as "source" and modify them as per requirements that come up
4. I will generate XSD back from modified Java classes to keep the XSD in-sync.

in this process any "documentation" on the XSD gets lost. (i.e. when i generate it from Java). Is there some way to get around this? Thanks.

Comment: Did you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244949/generate-xml-schema-with-documentation?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out but it says generated documentation in XSD is not possible(which answers part of my query). But my question is a larger one - if thats not possible, how do people keep java n XSD in sync? is that even required? am i approaching this wrong?

Comment: I would never recommend an approach where the primary source for XSDs be Java (or .NET for that matter) - hence me not answering your question (i.e. went for comments only :)....). You could still keep in sync the way you want, just not the comments... There are so many XSDs around that don't have annotations, that your case would fit the norm rather than being an exception....